# Async process pool executor not working in tornado

Tags: python, asynchronous, parallel-processing, tornado

I feel like I am far from good practice at this point. I am using tornado framework while also leveraging the ProcessPoolExecutor

```
import tornado.ioloop
import datetime
import tornado.web
import azure.functions as func
import json
import logging
import requests
import sys
import os
import pymongo
import mongo_config
import re
import concurrent.futures
from azure_model import Pytorch_Azure

MONGO_URL = mongo_config.uri()
mongo_client = pymongo.MongoClient(MONGO_URL)
db = mongo_client['db']
prods = mongo_client['db']['products']

pta = Pytorch_Azure()

def parallel_pred(img):
    r = requests.get(img, timeout = 10)
    img_id = img.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
    img_name = 'tmp{}.png'.format(img_id)
    with open(img_name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)
    prediction = pta.predict(img_name)
    os.remove(img_name)
    return prediction

class Predictionator(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def data_received(self, chunk):
        pass

    def get(self):
        merchant_id = self.get_argument('id', None, True)
        prod_type = self.request.uri.split('category=')[1].split('&id=')[0].replace('%20', ' ').replace('%26', '&').replace('%27', '\'')
        pred_list = []
        outputs = {}
        print(type(prod_type))
        if merchant_id and prod_type:

            counter = 0
            try:
                print(prod_type)
                for i in prods.find({'merchant': int(merchant_id), 'details.product_type':re.compile('^' + prod_type + '$', re.IGNORECASE)}):


                    prod_img = i['merchantImages'][0]
                    if prod_img not in pred_list:
                        pred_list.append(prod_img)
                        counter += 1
                        if counter == 5:
                            break
            except:
                self.write({'body': 'There was an error with the query. Please ensure you are using a correct merchant id and product type'})
            print(pred_list)

            if pred_list:

                try:   

                    executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(4)
                    for pred_out in executor.map(parallel_pred, pred_list, timeout = 15):
                            if pred_out['label'] not in outputs.keys():
                                outputs[pred_out['label']] = 1
                            else:
                                outputs[pred_out['label']] += 1


                except:
                    self.write({'body': 'There was an issue making the predictions.'})


                if outputs:
                    prediction = {}
                    prediction['label'] = max(outputs, key = outputs.get)
                    prediction['object_id'] = db.categories.find_one({'name':prediction['label']})['_id']

                    print(outputs)
                    self.write(json.dumps(prediction))
                else:
                    self.write({'statusCode': 400, 'body':'An error occurred.'})
            else:
                self.write({'statusCode': 400, 'body':'There were no results returned. Please ensure the id parameter has a valid merchant id and the category id has a valid product type'})
        else:
            self.write({'statusCode': 400, 'body':'Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body'})




def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r'/categorize',Predictionator),
    ])

def start_nado():
    print('starting nado')
    app = make_app()
    server = app.listen(8888)
    return server

def restart():
    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)

def stop_nado():
    ioloop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
    ioloop.add_callback(ioloop.stop)
    ioloop.add_callback(ioloop.close)
    print('stopping nado')

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            try:
                server = start_nado()
                tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().add_timeout(datetime.timedelta(seconds=600), stop_nado)
                tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
            except OSError:
                print('restarting')
                restart()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except OSError:
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance.stop()
        main()
```

The main issue comes with the Predictionator class. The idea is that it takes 5 products from a database and makes a prediction on each and return which class had the most predictions. That works fine, but it took a while, so we wanted to parallelize it with processes.
The first problem came with a hangup where it would make predictions on two and then become completely unresponsive. This is when the `tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().add_timeout(datetime.timedelta(seconds=600), stop_nado)` became the solution, to essentially restart the tornado server every 10 minutes.
After this, there was an `OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files` error. This is when the `restart` function became the [hacky] solution, which would  pretty much just restart the program.
This entire process worked pretty well for about 2 days and after this, the server it was running on became completely unresponsive. At this point, I am just looking for a point in the correct direction, I doubt tornado is the problem, but should I use a different framework altogether? I am pretty new to tornado and parallel processes with python.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're creating 4 new processes every time `if pred_list` condition is satisfied.

Generally, in Tornado programs you create a global `executor` object and reuse it.

```
# create a global object
executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(4)

class Predictionator(...):
    ...
    def get():
        ...
        # use the global `executor` object instead of creating a new one
        for pred_out in executor.map(...)
```

---

Another approach is to create `executor` in a `with...as` statement and these processes will be automatically closed and cleaned up when their tasks are done (please see the note at the end of the answer before using this method).

```
def get():
    ...
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(4) as executor:
        for pred_out in executor.map(...)
```

---

**Note:** First approach will give you better performance. In the second approach there's the overhead involved of creating and closing processes.

Comment: it seems so obvious now. Just as another quick question, is the 10 minute timeout okay or is that just nonsense I did trying to duct tape a problem?

Comment: @adam I don't think that's needed any more.